# Unity Check if object is clicked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please keep in mind that I'm new to unity. I created an 2D android game app.

I created a start button( from an image) and attacted a Box colider, and a C# script to it.

When I click the "button" I want the program to move to the next "Level", that Works except that I want it to only Work if i click the object and not everywhere on the game.

This is the C#:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class StartGame : MonoBehaviour {


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Application.LoadLevel("Game");
    }

}

}
```

I searched alot about this and maybe people say that to solve this you have to use, `Ray` and `RaycastHit` But I cant get that to Work either.

Here is what I tried to with `Ray` & `RaycastHit`

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if ((Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) || (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))) 
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        Ray ray;

        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        #elif (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IPHONE || UNITY_WP8)
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        #endif

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            Application.LoadLevel("Game");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be so appriciated.

Comment: Try to use OnClick method not Update

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to add box collider and script component including function below to the gameobject.

```
void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("Game");
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I'm guessing that the original code is not working on your scene, because you are using `box collider 2d`. `Physics.Raycast` is testing against 3D colliders. When I run it with the 3D version `box collider` it works fine.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [OnMouseDown()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html), which should replace the need to use `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))`